# unable to get check boxes value from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not able to get the checkboxes values from checkboxes to Firebase.

How will I be able to get each value from each box from each row?

Table:

[image]

Check boxes:

```
$("#table_body_Test").append("<tr><td>" + AgentEmail + "</td><td><INPUT TYPE=\"Checkbox\" Name=\"Browser\" Value =\"Agent\"></Input></td></tr>");
```

Table

```
 <div class="AgentDetailsRequest">

                  <table id="testTable"  align="center">
                    <thead>
                      <tr style="color: #D2002E; background: #FFCC01; height:32px;">
                        <td>Agents</td>
                        <td>Select</td>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="table_body_Test">
                    </tbody>
                  </table>

            </div>
```

full form

```
<div class="form-popup" id="myFormDetails">

      <div class="shipDetailsRequest">
      <form action="" method="post" class="form-container" >

              <button type="button" onclick="closeForm()" id="close">x</button>
              <input name="RR" type="RRField" id="date" disabled>
              <input name="RR" type="RRField" id="RRField" placeholder="RR Field" disabled>
              <p>Customer Details</p>
              <input onclick="sampleFunction()" type="number1" placeholder="Customer Account Number" name="customerAccountField" id="customerAccountField" required>
              <input  type="number1" placeholder="Customer Name" name="customerNameField" id="customerNameField" disabled>
              <p>Shipper Details</p>
              <input type="number1" placeholder="Shipper Name" name="senderName" id="shipperName" required>
              <textarea name="collectionAddress" placeholder="Collection Address...?" id="collectionAddress"></textarea>
              <p>Shipment Details</p>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Origin" name="shptOrigin" id="shipmentOrigin" maxlength = "3" required>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Destination" name="shptDest" id="shipmentDest" maxlength = "3" required>
              <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Weight" name="shptWeight" id="shptWeight" required>
              <input type="number" placeholder="Enter Pieces" name="shptPieces" id="shptPieces" required>
              <input type="number1" placeholder="Enter Dimensions" name="shptDimensions" id="shipmentDimensions" >
              <select placeholder="Choose Type" name="shptStack" id="shptStack" required>
                  <option value="Stackable">Stackable</option>
                  <option value="Nonstackable">Nonstackable</option>
                  </select>
              <select placeholder="Choose Desk" name="Desk" id="ChooseDesk" required>
                  <option value="KSA">KSA Desk</option>
                  <option value="DHA">DHA Desk</option>
                  <option value="RUH">RUH Desk</option>
                  <option value="JED">JED Desk</option>
                  </select>
              <p>Comment</p>
              <textarea name="comment" placeholder="Other Details...?" id="commentField"></textarea>

              <div class="mainDiv" align="center" >
                <input type="file" id="fileButton" />
                <progress  id="uploader" value="0" max="100" style="max-width: 128px;">0%</progress>  
              </div>

             <!-- <button id="submitBtn" onclick="ActionData()">Next</button> -->

             <button id="submitBtn" onclick="ActionData()">Next</button>
            </form>
          </div>
            <div class="AgentDetailsRequest">

                  <table id="testTable"  align="center">
                    <thead>
                      <tr style="color: #D2002E; background: #FFCC01; height:32px;">
                        <td>Agents</td>
                        <td>Select</td>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="table_body_Test">
                    </tbody>
                  </table>

            </div>
```

Full JavaScript

```
var DateText = document.getElementById("date");
var RRText = document.getElementById("RRField");
var CustAccText = document.getElementById("customerAccountField");
var CustNameText = document.getElementById("customerNameField");
var ShipperNameText = document.getElementById("shipperName");
var CollectionAddressText = document.getElementById("collectionAddress");
var ShipmentOrgText = document.getElementById("shipmentOrigin");
var ShipmentDestText = document.getElementById("shipmentDest");
var ShipmentweightText = document.getElementById("shptWeight");
var ShipmentPiecesText = document.getElementById("shptPieces");
var ShipmentDimensionsText = document.getElementById("shipmentDimensions");
var ShptStackText = document.getElementById("shptStack");
var ChooseDeskText = document.getElementById("ChooseDesk");
var CommentText = document.getElementById("commentField");

var ShipmentOriginValues = ShipmentOrgText.value;
ShipmentOriginValues = "All";

var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton');


if (ShipmentOrgText.value != null)
{

  var rootRefReAgents = firebase.database().ref().child("AgentsContact").child(ShipmentOriginValues);



  rootRefReAgents.on("child_added", snap =>{


    var AgentEmail = snap.child("Name").val();

    $("#table_body_Test").append("<tr><td>" + AgentEmail + "</td><td><INPUT TYPE=\"Checkbox\" Name=\"Browser\" Value =\"Agent\"></Input></td></tr>");

  });

}

function ActionData()
{
    //setting up values from Text Fields
    var DateValue = DateText.value;
    var RRValue = RRText.value;
    var CustAccountValue = CustAccText.value;
    var CustNameValue = CustNameText.value;
    var ShipperNameValue = ShipperNameText.value;
    var CollectionAddressValues = CollectionAddressText.value;
    ShipmentOriginValues = ShipmentOrgText.value;
    var ShipmentDestValues = ShipmentDestText.value;
    var ShipmentweightValues = ShipmentweightText.value;
    var ShipmentPiecesValues = ShipmentPiecesText.value;
    var ShipmentDimensionsValues = ShipmentDimensionsText.value;
    var ShptStackValues = ShptStackText.value;
    var ChooseDeskValues = ChooseDeskText.value;
    var CommentValues = CommentText.value;

    var FirebaseRef = firebase.database().ref("Requests").child(RRValue);


    if(RRValue && ShipmentOriginValues && ShipmentDestValues && CustAccountValue == null)
    {
        window.alert("Need More details to upload")
    }


   else
   {

   FirebaseRef.child("Date").set(DateValue);
   FirebaseRef.child("RR").set(RRValue);
   FirebaseRef.child("Customer Account").set(CustAccountValue);
   FirebaseRef.child("Customer Name").set(CustNameValue);
   FirebaseRef.child("Shipper Name").set(ShipperNameValue);
   FirebaseRef.child("Collection Address").set(CollectionAddressValues);
   FirebaseRef.child("Origin").set(ShipmentOriginValues);
   FirebaseRef.child("Destination").set(ShipmentDestValues);
   FirebaseRef.child("Weight").set(ShipmentweightValues);
   FirebaseRef.child("Pieces").set(ShipmentPiecesValues);
   FirebaseRef.child("Dimensions").set(ShipmentDimensionsValues);
   FirebaseRef.child("Stack").set(ShptStackValues);
   FirebaseRef.child("Desk").set(ChooseDeskValues);
   FirebaseRef.child("Comment").set(CommentValues);
   FirebaseRef.child("Status").set("Pending");
   //Uploading
   fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('img/'+RRValue+'/'+file.name);
    var task = storageRef.put(file);
    task.on('state_changed', function progress(snapshot) {
      var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes)*100;
      uploader.value = percentage;

    }, function error(err) {


    },function complete() {

    });
  }); 

   }

}
```

I need to check boxes from the table and get their values back to Firebase when form is submitted.

Comment: Let's see your table with data: If I understand your question, you get data from back-end, you feed the tbody of your table with this data, aren't you?

Comment: Yes i get data from backend to the table and then after i select the checkbox i need to send the selected to backend

Comment: Show us the result of the first part of your code: the table with data including the checkboxes

Comment: added a screen shot of how the table would look like

Comment: With the result of the first part of your code, I meant the "code generated":  the snippet of the source code of your HTML-page showing the table with the checkboxes.

Comment: I think that you have a pproblem with first part of your code: how are you setting the checked status of a checkbox? The code you provided is not correct. So tell us what is really your problem: are you interpreting and showing the data from back-end correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You could specify an id or name for each input and then retrieve their value when you submit the form.

```js
$("#table_body_Test").append("<tr><td>" + AgentEmail + "</td><td><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\""+AgentEmail+"\" Value =\"Agent\"></Input></td></tr>")

var agents = ... //Get your agents list from firebase
$form.on('submit', function(){
  agents.forEach(function(agent){
    if($('#'+agent.email).prop('checked'){
      //do something
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If your code is working, you can ckeck if a checkbox is checked with:

```
/* jQuery */
if ($('#check_id').is(":checked"))
{
  // checkbox is checked
}
```

you can also use:

```
/* jQuery */
$("#idOfCurrentRow").children()."input[type='checkbox']") is(":checked")
```

If you prefer pure JavaScript:

```
/* pure JavaScript*/
if(document.getElementById("idOfYourCheckbox").checked) {
   ...
} 
or
if (document.getElementByName("nameOfYourCheckbox").checked) {
   .....
}
```